# Hide row in JavaFX Tableview using FX-CSS?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-css

I am having this issue where I have a JavaFX Application which uses a Tableview consisting of TableColumns and is styled by a custom css.

Everything is working great, and I can add data into my tables/cells smoothly etc. However, if I want to present the user with only partial data a css solution would be optimal (instead of manipulating the data to fit the users requirements).

I have been looking into standard css and found that the "display: none" would be the optimal solution for hiding selected rows but keeping the data intact, but there seems to be no support of this for JavaFX.

I can't seem to find a good solution, other than manually hacking methods which modify the data of the cells to fit the needs.

I have used the setCellFactory to ex. highlight text or cells in different colors, and this works fine. But no solution for not displaying cells without ruining the overall experience of my application seems to work.

Has anyone had a similar issue and found a practical solution?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the selected row? Why just removing it from items list is not sufficient?

Comment: To display partial data, you would typically wrap your table data in a [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) and change the predicate on the filtered list. That way your underlying data stays intact, but the data displayed can vary.

Comment: Yes, this is my solution at the moment, however I am going to have to use quite sophisticated ways of manipulating this data (collapsing some messages etc) and was hoping that CSS could make this job a lot easier and more efficient. However it seems that there is no css workaround for JavaFX-css.

Comment: It would be much harder to apply logic to manipulate the css than to apply logic to manipulate the `FilteredList`. The `FilteredList` is designed for this use case; CSS is not.

Answer (score 4):

## If you want to use CSS

Every `Node` has a `visibility` css property
[JavaFX CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node)
So I would try:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

But I don't know if it hides whole row or what, if there will be a trouble, you can hid the internal `Label` in each cell

---

### EDIT:

And what about this workaround:

```
-fx-text-fill: transparent;
```

for each row or `Label`
This "hides" the text but row will stay visible
Not tested, just an idea

---

### EDIT (2):

This can help:

```
-fx-cell-size: 0;
```

For each cell in row
But this is a part of your own idea

Comment: So I tried using this, and it seems that the "visibility:collapse;" does the trick atleast when manipulating an entire column. I will try to use this to see if a single row can be manipulated the same way. Thanks!

Comment: On closer inspection, neither this fix or the "visibility:hidden|collapse" removes the actual space it uses, rendering the use for this in my case useless..

Comment: I think you missunderstood my intentions. I want the "row" to disappear visually. I am trying to use your edited implementation in combination with setting the acutal cell size to 0, but without much luck.

Comment: So my ideas are gone :/, but your way with 0 height could solve the problem. so try to set `-fx-cell-size` to 0 http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell @jensd

Comment: Why you all reference to the old JavaFX CSS Reference? If you use Java 8, they've added a lot more, so then please look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: None of the above worked for me (with TreeTableView) when trying to hide empty rows at the bottom which can appear when nodes are collapsed. This works perfectly though:

    .tree-table-row-cell:empty {
        -fx-opacity: 0;
    }

Answer (score 1):

There is no `-fx-visibility` CSS property, but you could work around it by using a combination of things, like:

```
-fx-pref-width: 0;
-fx-opacity: 0;
```